# touch events in linux using Qt

Tags: linux, qt, touch

I am trying to program touch events in linux using Qt. My touch screen works, however when I touch the screen I get mouse events rather than touch events. The mouse cursor moves to where I touch the screen. I don't know if it is a Qt problem or something that happens at the OS level.

I am using Qt 5.4.0 on Debian Jessie.

Comment: This is common problem that touchscreen generates mouse events instead of touch events and it is also problematic for me, so I started bounty. I am using "Finger Paint" from Qt official examples: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-touch-fingerpaint-example.html

Comment: By now I can hardly recall why I asked the question in the first place, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Maybe `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents, false);` ?

Comment: @dtech no, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not share any source code, its hard to know what happens wrong on your side. Take a look at this documentation:

- [Detailed Description of `QTouchEvent` Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#details)
- [Touch Input Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/examples-touch.html)

All that examples works well, and you need to test it on your side. If it will not work for you, it means that there are some problems on your side, otherwise, it mean that you forgot something in your application (like `Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents` attribute set, or not set to `true` the `acceptTouchEvents` attribute at graphics items...).

Comment: @troyance, I do have that attribute set. I've noticed that when I work in GNOME it does work (I was previously working in KDE), so it could be a problem with KDE which has nothing to do with Qt.